# Run a function after the other with specific time interval

Tags: google-apps-script

I am very new in google app script and script writing in general.

I have two function **function Pops()** and **function Tiger()**

Function Pops is triggered **on form Submit**

I want **function Tiger()** to run 60 seconds after the **function Pops()** completed its action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can programmatically create a new time-based trigger with [`ScriptApp.newTrigger( functionName )`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#newTrigger(String))

```
function Pops(){
    // your logic goes here

    ScriptApp.newTrigger( 'Tiger' ).timeBased().after( 60 * 1000 ).create();
}

function Tiger( event ){
    // your logic goes here

    // remove this trigger
    if ( ( event.triggerUid || '' ).length ) {
        var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();

        for ( var trigger of triggers ) {
            if ( trigger.getUniqueId() === event.triggerUid ) {
                ScriptApp.deleteTrigger( trigger );

                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```